# Minikube pods stuck in Waiting: ImagePullBackOff

Tags: minikube

I have a new minikube installation running on a Centos 8 VM (VirtualBox) and when I run

```
kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
```

the pod runs but gets stuck in "Waiting: ImagePullBackOff". Looking further into this I can see that minikube cannot resolve DNS or download from the internet. The host can download and other Docker containers can access the internet too. Running ping inside minikube ssh doesn't seem to work either (ping not there)

```
[john@localhost ~]$ minikube ssh -- ping google.com
bash: ping: command not found
ssh: exit status 127
```

And curl returns that it cannot resolve DNS

```
[john@localhost ~]$ minikube ssh -- curl www.google.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com
ssh: exit status 6
```

So it looks to me that minikube cannot access the internet. I'm sure I have missed something very simple here so if anyone could tell me I would be very grateful. I have no proxies.

Comment: Hi, does `minikube ssh -- curl -s 172.217.169.206` command return anything?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the answer. It was the Centos firewall. These commands fixed it.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0 --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```